# How to plot a 3D smooth mesh figure in matlab with existing XYZ coordination?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mesh

For example I have XYZ coordinates:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5];
Y = [2,2,4,7,1];
Z = [0.96,0.52,0.74,0.10,0.33];
```

Microsoft Excel could not plot a smooth mesh. Is Matlab possible to plot a smooth mesh figure? If yes, please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I got your intention correctly, you can use [`fill3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html):

```
fill3(X,Y,Z,Z)
shading interp
```

[image]